# Keep model from going out of a window

Tags: javascript

Hi guys so i am making a simple game, and following this tutorial [Here](http://www.zekechan.net/asteroids-html5-game-tutorial-2/)

I am up to the bit for which the ship can go out of bounds and then re appear onto the other side using this code:

```
checkBoundaries: function (sprite) {
        if (sprite.x < 0) {
            sprite.x = game.width;
        } else if (sprite.x > game.width) {
            sprite.x = 0;
        } 

        if (sprite.y < 0) {
            sprite.y = game.height;
        } else if (sprite.y > game.height) {
            sprite.y = 0;
        }
    },
```

However i am new to this and learning so i was wondering what is the way to keep it from not going out of bounds, so it hits like a wall and it cant go out of bounds and re appear but just stay there

Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch what happens for each condition:

```
checkBoundaries: function (sprite) {
        if (sprite.x < 0) {
            sprite.x = 0;
        } else if (sprite.x > game.width) {
            sprite.x = game.width;
        } 

        if (sprite.y < 0) {
            sprite.y = 0;
        } else if (sprite.y > game.height) {
            sprite.y = game.height;
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thats amazing, 1 more question those if thats aright, like i actually just want the tip to touch before it goes completey out of bounds if u get what i mean, so now it goes all the way to the boom , so do i need to change the height or something?

Comment: Yeah, adjust:  `if (sprite.x < 0) {` and `} else if (sprite.x > game.width) {` by adding/subtracting a few pixels at a time until they're correct.  For example:  First try:  ` `if (sprite.x < 10) {`  and `} else if (sprite.x > game.width - 10) {`

Comment: Glad to help.  If your problem is resolved, don't forget to mark a correct answer so this question is resolved. Thanks!